# How do I webscrape article urls from this news website using rvest?

Tags: r, rvest

I'm very new to coding and am attempting to scrape all the article URLs from a news website. I've successfully scraped the article title, author, dates, and summaries and placed them into a data frame, but I'm unable to follow the same process for scraping the URLs. I'm using the Selector Gadget but can't seem to pick the right element.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
link="https://www.theroot.com/news/criminal-justice"
webpage=read_html(link)
articlelinks= webpage%>% html_nodes(".diJdnO")%>% html_attr("href")
```

I'm receiving a vector of 20 "NAs." I would love any assistance correcting this code!

Comment: Only the first page or do you need multiple?

Comment: I'm going to eventually need multiple pages, but trying just the first page first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion for multiple pages of scraping.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

get_articles <- function(n_articles) {
  page <- paste0("https://www.theroot.com/news/criminal-justice",
                 "?startIndex=",
                 n_articles) %>%
    read_html()
  
  tibble(
    title = page %>%
      html_elements(".aoiLP .js_link") %>%
      html_text2(),
    author = page %>%
      html_elements(".llHfhX .js_link , .permalink-bylineprop") %>%
      html_text2(),
    date = page %>%
      html_elements(".js_meta-time") %>%
      html_text2(),
    url = page %>%
      html_elements(".aoiLP .js_link") %>%
      html_attr("href")
  )
}

df <- map_dfr(seq(0, 200, by = 20), get_articles)

df %>%
  slice(1:10) %>%
  mutate(content = map(url, ~ read_html(.x) %>%
                         html_elements(".bOfvBY") %>%
                         html_text2 %>% 
                         paste(collapse = ","))) %>% 
  unnest(content)
```

Comment: Could I also add the actual articles into the data frame? I've created code to do it with one article, but would like to repeat it for every article I'm scraping and placing into the data frame:

'
get_article=function(article_link) {
  article_link="https://www.theroot.com/mississippi-man-arrested-for-attempting-to-hit-black-ch-1849342160"%>% 
  article_page=read_html()%>% 
  article_body=article_page%>% html_nodes(".bOfvBY")%>% html_text() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
}

'''
here's the example of doing it for one article, is there a away to add this to the function you've created?

Comment: @JoshuaCrutchfield Yes, I have added a solution for that. A new column with the content from each article. I did this for only the first 10 articles

Comment: Hi @TomHoel Question: How could this code be rewritten to look for a specific range of dates? I think I need a static data set because the website structure keeps changing and the outputs sometimes throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

page <- "https://www.theroot.com/news/criminal-justice" %>% 
  read_html()
  
tibble(
  url = page %>%  
    html_elements(".aoiLP") %>% 
    html_elements(".js_link") %>% 
    html_attr("href"),
  title = page %>%  
    html_elements(".aoiLP") %>% 
    html_elements(".js_link") %>% 
    html_text2()
)

# A tibble: 20 x 2
   url                                                                title
   <chr>                                                              <chr>
 1 https://www.theroot.com/brooklyn-bishop-gets-robbed-at-gunpoint-d~ Broo~
 2 https://www.theroot.com/georgia-gov-brian-kemp-to-testify-on-trum~ Geor~
 3 https://www.theroot.com/florida-to-allow-military-veterans-teach-~ Flor~
 4 https://www.theroot.com/one-of-george-floyd-s-killers-gets-senten~ One ~
 5 https://www.theroot.com/judge-finds-enough-evidence-to-pursue-cri~ Judg~
 6 https://www.theroot.com/indiana-man-arrested-in-connection-to-bla~ Indi~
 7 https://www.theroot.com/this-is-not-a-george-floyd-situation-says~ “Thi~
 8 https://www.theroot.com/three-men-exonerated-in-horrible-1995-sub~ Thre~
 9 https://www.theroot.com/naacp-calls-on-department-of-justice-to-i~ NAAC~
10 https://www.theroot.com/autopsy-jayland-walker-suffered-46-bullet~ Auto~
11 https://www.theroot.com/detroit-to-pay-7-5m-to-black-man-who-clai~ Detr~
12 https://www.theroot.com/pro-trump-man-charged-for-staging-arson-a~ Pro-~
13 https://www.theroot.com/footage-of-uvalde-school-shooting-stirs-a~ Foot~
14 https://www.theroot.com/akron-recognizes-jayland-walker-s-funeral~ Akro~
15 https://www.theroot.com/jayland-walker-family-and-legal-team-addr~ Jayl~
16 https://www.theroot.com/white-man-makes-over-100-racist-threats-a~ Whit~
17 https://www.theroot.com/wisconsin-supreme-court-allows-chrystul-k~ Wisc~
18 https://www.theroot.com/kamala-harris-calls-for-assault-weapons-b~ Kama~
19 https://www.theroot.com/jayland-walker-s-sister-speaks-out-follow~ Jayl~
20 https://www.theroot.com/mississippi-judges-block-new-dna-tests-in~ Miss~
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

[image]

Comment: @JoshuaCrutchfield Whats the error?